# Keys/indexes for revisions of user submitted text

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, indexing, primary-key

I have a table:

```
id:int
revision:int
text:ntext
```

In general I will need to retrieve the latest revision of text for a particular id, or (considerably less frequently) add a new row containing a new revision for a particular id. Bearing this in mind, it would be a good idea to put indexes on the `id` and `revision` columns. I don't have a problem with implementing this, but I'm wondering if this is a situation where it would be sensible to use a composite (multi-field) index/key composed of both `id` and `revision`, or if there is any other strategy that would be appropriate for my use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the performance difference between a composite index and two separate indexes would be noticeable, but, as usual, I suggest trying both and profiling if the absolute best performance is needed.

You are likely to always be querying on both fields, with a definite `id` and an unknown `revision` occasionally (when needing to find the max `revision` for an `id`).  If your composite index is `(id,revision)` then this use case is supported by the index.  Querying on `id` alone with no care for `revision` also works.

If it is ever likely that you will be querying on `revision` only without regard to `id` then you will need two separate indexes.

You will also want to analyze the impact that either index has on `insert` performance.  The composite index will cluster on both fields, whereas the two separate indexes will cluster only on `id`.

*EDIT: typos.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems it the majority of cases you will be selecting the record based on both id and revision - therefore for quickest lookups you should make id and revision your composite primary key.

Comment: Sure, but given that I will not know in advance what the latest revision is, will this give any advantage?

Comment: Your primary key will be clustered, which means the data shall be physically placed together on disk.  This is quicker for selects as it does not have to leap all over the disk(s).  Your inserts may suffer though, this is the trade off.

Answer (score 1):

If id is the primary key its already indexed (I don't use SqlServer)
I seems that your revision is unique too.
so I think it would be better to use separate indexes and put unique constraint on revision (if required).